# CP Framework/Solver for .Net Core

Tags: solver, cplex, constraint-programming, or-tools

First I want to say that I'm very new to this field.

As far as I understand it, there are two different ways to use a Constraint Programming (CP) Solver:

1. Using the API from the Solver itself. For example .Net Interface for [IBM ILOG CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/products/ilog-cplex-optimization-studio).
2. Using a Framework that works with many solvers. The Framework translates the constrains in the format that the chosen solver can read. For example, [AMPL](https://ampl.com).

There is a related [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/732/how-to-select-a-constraint-programming-solver) that gives a very good explanation and insights.
@Rob posted a very detailed answer with many solvers. The disadvantage is that the list shows, in that language the solvers are coded and not in which they can be used. Also, it's not up to date.

The Problem that I want to solve is a Job Shop scheduling problem, which also has parallel machines. It is for planning real production and not a research project.

The project is programmed in .Net Core, so I am looking for a solver or a framework that has a compatible API for .Net Core. The desired is a framework that can use various solvers in the background.

I found that [CPLEX](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSSA5P_12.8.0/ilog.odms.ide.help/OPL_Studio/usroplinterfaces/topics/opl_interf_intro_dotnet.html) has an interface for .NET.

The second is [Google OR](https://developers.google.com/optimization/install/dotnet/), there @Laurent Perron answerded in the [question](https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/1504/what-is-the-purpose-of-libraries-like-pyomo-and-google-or-tools):

> Now, to answer you questions, the goal of OR-Tools is to interact with
>   the scientific community and the OR community. This being said, we are
>   very pleased to see a large community of commercial users relying on
>   it for their business, and we do our best to support them.

So this two might be possiblities.

So, my question is, "Doe's anyone have experience with using frameworks/solvers for Constraint Programming in .Net Core?"

Also, I appreciate any suggestion to find links of more frameworks/solvers that are compatible with .Net Core.

Comment: We just use OR-Tools internally at Google. Does it qualifies as real world use ? This being said, it is true that .NET is only used externally. But we have dedicated users for this API.

Comment: AFAIK, few solvers can use Cp to solve scheduling problems and some of them have capability to use .NET API (E.g. CPLEX). Would you like just using Cp or could you develop a MIP for your problem?

Comment: @abbasomidi I'm new to this field and have not many background. Maybe it's possible to devolope this as a MIP, but not sure.
Have you a MIP Framework for .Net that you can recommend me?

Comment: @LaurentPerron thanks for your comment, I have misunderstand this. The question have been updated with the new informations.

Answer (score 1):

As you mentioned, you will need to develop a practical (non-academic) scheduling model, you have two different options.

- First, if your problem scale is not too large, I recommend developing a MIP formulation for your problem. Indeed, you could achieve an optimal solution. Some useful examples have been found via [this](http://amsterdamoptimization.com/models/blog/ft10.gms), [this](https://www.gams.com/latest/gamslib_ml/libhtml/gamslib_flowshop.html) or [this](https://mipcl-cpp.appspot.com/static/pdf/OM.pdf) links.
- Second, if your problem is the large scale that MIP solvers can not solve it in a reasonable time,  you should use other techniques like CP.
  However, CP has a suboptimal solution but, in the large scale model, it can solve the problem in a reasonable time. Some useful example in the CP could be found via [this](https://www.slideshare.net/PhilippeLaborie/vug-scheduling28-may2014) or [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/forums/html/topic?id=02ecc339-015e-490e-b5a2-5bdf8d86f15d) links.

In both cases, you will need a solver such as CPLEX to solve MIP or CP, or you can use an open-source solver such as [MIPCL](https://mipcl-cpp.appspot.com/). Might, you want to use some ASP software that I recommended [ASPROVA](https://www.asprova.com/en/) or [MRPEasy](https://www.mrpeasy.com).

Comment: Please, this looks like CP-Bashing. I truly believe that CPO optimizer is the best scheduling solver around, and much better than MIP formulations on any MIP solver on average. I know Gurobi, CPLEX, XPress are fantastic tools, but for large scale scheduling, it is unbeatable.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, I'm pretty sure, (according to my experience) some state-of-the-art solvers such as CPLEX or GUROBI can solve large scale MIPs in a reasonable time. I recommended using them but, if you like just using CP, [this](https://www.solver.com/solver-sdk-platform-solver-engines#Integer%20and%20Constraint%20Programming%20Problems) and [this](https://www.minizinc.org/software.html) links might be useful. It should be noted that [GAMS](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/apis/dotnet/DOTNET_OVERVIEW.html) has a very good .NET API but, I don't know it supports CP solver or NOT.

Comment: First comment, the bragging part. Our solver won 4 gold medals at the last minizinc challenge.

Comment: Second comment. I am sorry, I meant using Gurobi to solve large scheduling problems. The initial question is about solving scheduling problems. I believe CP has proven to be good at it, and CPO is very good at it, better than MIP solvers. Furthermore, I believe the API to solve scheduling problems using CPO or OR-Tools is much nicer than what you need to write to solve the same problems using a linear formulation.

Comment: @LaurentPerron, very well. If you know what you want, you would go ahead. :)

Comment: @LaurentPerron According to your experience, what is the best *open-source* solver for large scale scheduling problems (could you precise what "large scale" means here). What i I want to use other method than an off-the-helf solver, what method is proven to be efficient ?

Comment: I would suggest OR-Tools + decomposition of the model to break the scaling limit.

Comment: @LaurentPerron Could you elaborate on what do you mean exactly by "scaling limit" (I checked wikipedia but I am not sure about my understanding)

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about CP solvers, but for FICO Xpress the .NET .dll also works for .NET core. So I would suspect that similar transferability is also applicable for CP solvers.

The reason is in my opinion fairly clear: the API .dlls (the ones that contain the classes and methods accessible in .NET Core) are pretty simple, and the heavy lifting is done in the C part of the library.

To check whether a given .dll is compatible with .NET core, check out the .[NET portability analyzer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/analyzers/portability-analyzer) from Windows.